# How can I get access to tools for debugging, etc., in a docker container?

Tags: docker

Docker images are typically really stripped down and don't include all the utilities you might want to have at your fingertips when debugging an issue.  Is there some way to easily get access to all these utilities to debug a running container?  In theory I think I could attach a volume with binaries, but most conveniences I would want are not just static binaries, and in general there is not good tooling around this.  Another option could be to build separate "debuggable" images, but that is a pain and also requires that you can reproduce the problem in a fresh container.

Comment: You can install your debugging tools into the image. It'll make it bigger, but if you frequently find yourself needing to debug code in containers, go for it. Once your code stabilizes you could focus on making images smaller and more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  Seems like there is room for someone to create a better solution though.

Comment: If you just want to correct code for your website hosted in a container, you could also just mount your source code as an external volume and doing changes directly from the OS hosting your container.

Comment: did you try with docker exec?

Comment: Once the container is assumed to be buggy I would `docker exec -it my-buggy-container bash`  into it and install the debugging tools needed. Otherwise you can create a base image with the usual debugging you use and create a specific debugging image `FROM debugging-image`. No debugging tools are offer as it can be networking debugging tools, or binary debugging tool, or performance debugging tools, and no way of offering them properly (the services included in an image are expected to be stable)